# Do different C compilers have different argument passing rules?

Tags: c, compiler-construction

```
#‎include‬<stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
   int a=10;
   printf("%d, %d, %d\n", a, a++, ++a);
   return 0;
}
```

**This is showing 12 11 12 in 32 bit gcc compiler
and 12 11 11 in 16 bit turbo c compiler.
Do differecnt C compilers have different argument passing rules?**

Comment: and again this question...this is Undefined in C standard that why, different compilers use different order C don't give an order

Comment: Please write "different" when you mean "different", `diff` is something very specific to programmers. It took way too long to understand your question.

Comment: Why this one agaiiiiiin.......? Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17250452/unexpected-behavior-of-printf) and also [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473706/understanding-sequence-point-in-c)

Comment: In SO13 this question is defined as "possible duplicate, no answer required". The participants are allowed to whine and make snide remarks in comments. I hear they work on the SO14 draft which would require this question to result in demons actually flying out of poster's nose.

Comment: If I could set-up a filter for this question, I would -- can we delete this? It provides no useful information for users.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/evalorder2.html), Expressions.

> Q: Under my compiler, the code
>
> int i = 7; printf("%d\n", i++ * i++);
>
> prints 49. Regardless of the order of evaluation, shouldn't it print
>   56?