# Undefined behavior and sequence point

Tags: c, undefined-behavior, expression, sequence-points

From past few days I was trying to learn about [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Few days ago I found a [c-faq](http://www.c-faq.com/) link. This helps a lot to clear many confusions, but creates an another big confusion when I read the question [#3.8](http://www.c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html). After my lots of efforts to understand the statement (specially second  sentence);

The Standard states that

> *Between the previous and next [sequence point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression. Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored.*

I felt better to ask this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17473706/understanding-sequence-point-in-c) on SO but none of the answer there explained the second sentence of this statement. Finally, I got an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056443/2455888) there about this point . After reading it and FAQ many times **I concluded** that;

1.The last sentence

> ***Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the value to be stored***

would be like this;

> *Furthermore, the prior value **of an object**  shall be accessed only to determine the **modified/new** value(  **of same object** ) to be stored.*

As it is clear by the example

```
 int i = 1, j, a[5];    
 i = i + 1;
 j = i + 1;
 a[i] = i;
```

in case of expression `i = i + 1` prior value (which is `1` here) of `i` (in R.H.S) is accessed to determine the value of `i` to be stored. While in case of `j = i + 1`  and `a[i] = i`, the accessed value of  i  is *just value* **not** *prior* value as no where `i`  is modified in these statements.

2.In case of expression `a[i] = i++` or `a[i++] = i`,  first sentence of above statement

> ***Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.***

**get failed** as  `i`  is *modified only once between two consecutive sequence point*. And that's why we need second sentence.
Both of these examples are disallowed in C because the prior value  of  `i`  accessed two times i.e, `i++`  itself access *prior value* of  `i`  in the expression to modify it  and hence other access of *prior value / value* of  `i`  is needless as it is not accessed to determine the modified value to be stored.

The problem starts when I came up with the expression `i = i++` about which it is stated in c-faq

> *Actually, the other expressions we've been discussing are in violation of the second sentence, as well.*

I think in this expression `i` (in R.H.S) is accessed to determine the modified value of `i`.
**How this expression is violating the second statement?**

Answer (score 2):

Think about it this way:

```
a = i++;
```

is equivalent to:

```
a = i;
i++;
```

The accesses the value of `i` in the increment has nothing to do with determining what value a will be stored into a. So `i = i++` contains two modifications of `i` (which is disallowed by the first sentence), but also, the `i =` modification to `i` is independent from one of the accesses to `i` in `i++`.

I think someone was just being extra clever there. There's no need to figure how much an undefined behavior is undefined. Modifying a value twice is enough undefined.

Comment: Well, to be pedantic, it's undefined how many times it gets accessed because the whole expression is undefined.